# tab control through text boxes

Tags: tabs, textbox, settings

Objective C - iOS programming. I have a static table view controller with three cells with three text boxes in each cell. Is there a setting I can utilize that will allow me to set the order in which I tab through the text boxes?

Comment: which Language are using ?

Comment: are u talking about Java,.Net or something else?

Comment: Sorry , Three may be the TabIndex / TAbOrder property should be there in Objective C